# how to drag and drop from one HTML table to another?

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I am looking for some miracle right now, since I am on really on a tight schedule and really need a script that would alow users to drag and drop 'rows' from one HTML table to another. And after all the " draggin & dropin' " a save button should simply add the newly dropped items to the real backend MySQL through a php script!

I would really appreciate it if someone out there could help me!! 
cheers! 
Ali

Comment: So, you need something that rewrites the html, and records the change so that on-submit it can let the php script know about it? (edit:typo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll take a bit of work, but you can probably use jQuery UI for this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

It provides dragging, dropping, sorting and events for sending the new list contents to your script.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

It has everything you need to get going. Check out connecting 2 lists.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: sorry, didn't see your answer or I wouldn't have posted.

Comment: just because you answered it a little later doesn't make your answer any less correct, and your effort any less appreciated! thank you!